# FullCalendar does not change language

Tags: javascript, calendar, fullcalendar, locale

I have my jsp file where to include the local-all javaScript file, in my other file where my calendar starts I try to call the code 'es' to change it to Spanish and nothing happens.

jsp file where you included the script

```
<script src="js/lib/calendar/locales-all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

javascript code where I invoke the locale: es

```
!function ($) {
    "use strict";

    var CalendarApp = function () {
        this.$body = $("body")
        this.$modal = $('#event-modal'),
                this.$event = ('#external-events div.external-event'),
                this.$calendar = $('#calendar'),
                this.$saveCategoryBtn = $('.save-category'),
                this.$categoryForm = $('#add-category form'),
                this.$extEvents = $('#external-events'),
                this.$calendarObj = null;
    };


    /* on drop */
    CalendarApp.prototype.onDrop = function (eventObj, date) {
        var $this = this;
        // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
        var originalEventObject = eventObj.data('eventObject');
        var $categoryClass = eventObj.attr('data-class');
        // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
        var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
        // assign it the date that was reported
        copiedEventObject.start = date;
        start = moment(start).format('YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm');

        if ($categoryClass)
            copiedEventObject['className'] = [$categoryClass];
        // render the event on the calendar
        $this.$calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);
        // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
        if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
            // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
            eventObj.remove();
        }
    },
            /* on click on event */
            CalendarApp.prototype.onEventClick = function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                window.location.href="Cita?opcion=6&textId="+ calEvent.id +"&textEstado=1";
            },
                    
            CalendarApp.prototype.enableDrag = function () {
                //init events
                $(this.$event).each(function () {
                    // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
                    // it doesn't need to have a start or end
                    var eventObject = {
                        title: $.trim($(this).text()) // use the element's text as the event title
                    };
                    // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
                    $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);
                    // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
                    $(this).draggable({
                        zIndex: 999,
                        revert: true, // will cause the event to go back to its
                        revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
                    });
                });
            };
    /* Initializing */
    CalendarApp.prototype.init = function () {
        this.enableDrag();
        /*  Initialize the calendar  */
        var ide = document.getElementsByName("id");
        var fecha = document.getElementsByName("fecha");
        var nombre = document.getElementsByName("nombre");
        var horaInicio = document.getElementsByName("horaInicio");
        var horaFin = document.getElementsByName("horaFin");
        var id="";
        var dia = "";
        var titulo = "";
        var inicio = "";
        var fin = "";

        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();
        var form = '';
        var today = new Date($.now());
        var citas=[];
       
       for (var x = 0; x < nombre.length; x++) {
            var defaultEvents ={
                    id: id + ide[x].value,
                    title: titulo + nombre[x].value,
                    start: dia + fecha[x].value + 'T' + inicio + horaInicio[x].value,
                    end: dia + fecha[x].value + 'T' + fin + horaFin[x].value,
                    className: 'bg-primary'
                };
                citas.push(defaultEvents);
            } 
            var $this = this; 
      
            $this.$calendarObj = $this.$calendar.fullCalendar({
                header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
                locale: "es", 
                events: citas,
                editable: true,
                eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) { $this.onEventClick(calEvent, jsEvent, view); }
            });
          
       
       
    },
            //init CalendarApp
            $.CalendarApp = new CalendarApp, $.CalendarApp.Constructor = CalendarApp;

}(window.jQuery),
//initializing CalendarApp
        function ($) {
            "use strict";
            $.CalendarApp.init()
        }(window.jQuery);
```

In my console it sends me an error in my locale-all file in the first line

```
[].push.apply(FullCalendar.globalLocales, function () {
  'use strict';
```

[image]

Comment: The name of the option is `locale` - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/locale . Not sure where you got `localesAll` from as an option. It certainly isn't mentioned anywhere in the documentation. That's the name of a JS file, not a fullCalendar option. Try `locale: "es"` and it should work.

Comment: I also tried like this, but it doesn't work for me

Comment: It should work fine, if you use that file and the code I've shown. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/WNGQRvW . Have you got any console errors? Did the locale file definitely load correctly? If you have a scenario where it's not working, we'll need enough code / info to understand why it's causing a problem

Comment: friend already enter information about the console, send me an error in the archi locale-all in the first line of code you can see above the question edited

Comment: Let me explain I have a template, this web template has the fullcalendar plugin, mainly it has two files that are executed by elc alendar, which is the fullCalendar-init and fullCaledar-min, this plugin is new for me, I do not know how to change the language I have consulted but I don't it turns out but there has to be a solution,I uploaded all the complete code to see if you can see something else

Comment: Sorry I just noticed that the error you posted is actually happening  inside the locales-all file, not in your code. I didn't notice immediately, so apologies. If I had to guess, I would say that this problem is likely to happen if you include the locales script in your page before the fullCalendar script, because it depends on the fullCalendar script...so if that isn't loaded yet, it will have a problem. Make sure they are loaded in the correct order

Comment: I had thought exactly the same thing before and I had already done it but it did not work for me

Comment: Something else I just realised too...you are using fullCalendar 3, correct? But it looks like you have loaded the locales file for fullCalendar 5. As per the v3 docs for the "locale" option (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/locale), the file you need is called `locale-all.js` (not `locales-all.js`), and you need to make sure you download the v3 version of it, so it knows how to work with the main v3 fullCalendar. e.g. if you're running 3.9 you must download the 3.9 version of locale-all.js. If you run 3.10 you must download the 3.10 version, etc.

Comment: Possibly it is that, but as I told you, this fullcalendar comes with a template and I don't know what version it is, do you know how I do to know which version I'm using?

Comment: I can see it because of the syntax, it changed from version 4 onwards to not be a jQuery plugin and the way to create the calendar changed. So I can recognise it like that (and so can you if you compare the examples in the different versions of the fullCalendar documentation). But also if you open the fullCalendar.js file in your template, it should show the version at the start of the file.